# Too much free space after a "tcolorbox"

Tags: tcolorbox, amsthm

[image]

Hi to everybody. I have a problem with my thesis. I used the library "theorems" of tcolorbox. But when i use the ambient proof (i.e. \begin{proof}) there is too much space between the end of the box and the beginning of the proof (as shown in the image). What do you think i can do? Note that this only happens when i use the ambient proof.
On the other hand, i would like to put some space after a box in general, i.e. i would like to put some space between the end of a box and the text that follows.

Thanks to everybody.

```
       \documentclass[twoside,9pt,b5paper]{extbook}

       \usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false]{geometry}

       \usepackage{changepage}

       \usepackage[a4,center]{crop}

        \geometry{%
         includeheadfoot,
         margin=2.6cm
         }

        \usepackage{soul}

        \usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

        \usetikzlibrary{calc}

        \usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}

       \usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}

       \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

      \usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

      \definecolor{indigo(dye)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}
      \usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = indigo(dye),
        filecolor=black,
        urlcolor  = black!40!cyan,
        citecolor = indigo(dye),
        anchorcolor = red!60!black]{hyperref}
       \hypersetup{linktocpage}
       \usepackage{tcolorbox}

       \usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty,explicit]{titlesec}

       \usepackage{fancyhdr}

       \usepackage{anyfontsize}

       \usepackage{palatino,eulervm}

      \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion]{microtype}

      \usepackage{eqparbox}

      \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
      \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} %per il TOC

      \usepackage{graphicx}
      \def\chk#1{#1^{\smash{\scalebox{.7}[1.4]{\rotatebox{90}{\guilsinglleft}}}}}

      \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

      \newtheorem{cor}{Corollario}

      \renewcommand{\square}{ \tikz[baseline=-.2ex] \filldraw [fill=black!35!white, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (1ex,1ex) ;} 

      \newtheorem{example}{\square \; Esempio}

      \renewcommand{\blacksquare}{\tikz[baseline=-.2ex] \filldraw [fill=black, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (1ex,1ex) ;}

      \renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

      \linespread{1} 

      \makeatletter              
     \renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
     \makeatother

     \tcbuselibrary{theorems}

     \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{propn}{Proposizione}{coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!35!white,fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign colon}{propn}

     \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theo}{Teorema}{coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!35!white,fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign colon}{theo}

     \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lemma}{Lemma}{coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!35!white,fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign colon}{lem}

      \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}{Definizione}{leftrule=2mm, coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!35!white, fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign colon}{defn}

     \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{examp}{\square \; Esempio}{coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=white, colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash,terminator sign colon}{examp}

    \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{corol}{Corollario}{coltitle=black, detach title, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}, colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!35!white,fonttitle=\bfseries, arc=0mm, separator sign dash, description delimiters={\grqq}{\grqq}, terminator sign colon}{corol}


    \newtcbox{\mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small \leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\small \rightmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

    \renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
    \renewcommand\cftsecfont{\scshape}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal code that exhibits this symptom.

Comment: It seems to work with the code i put. I don't know why, because the preamble is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is not complete. It misses an example (that shows the issue). It is also not really minimal. In any case, if you cannot provide a code that exhibits the issue, how do you think others may fix it?

Comment: In some part of the document the space is bigger, in some part is normal. I just can say this... Thank you for your help.

Comment: This happens if some of the objects are rather large, and LaTeX does its best to fill the pages uniformly. It might be that making the `tcolorbox`es `breakable`  ameliorates the situation.

Comment: Oh,  Ok! I'll try to make the boxes breakable!